# What is the correct way to extend / modify a view of external app in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm working on a Django project and I have a few external apps that are installed to my virtual-env.

One of the app has a feature to upload a file by defining an `def upload` and route the `/upload` to it in the `urls.py`

Now I want to added some features such as `@login_required` to the method or sending the `request.user` together with the parameters.

I can do it by changing directly to the external app code, however It shall breaks if the app is upgraded.

I try to copy the the `views.py` of the app to my local `app` folder under the same name and write my own code there but It doesn't seem to work (as template modification)

Is there other options for me ? Thanks !

Comment: FWIW, if all you need to do is wrap the view with decorators, you can do that in urls.py: `(r'/some/view/', login_required(upload_view))`

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the external app's view with your own view. In your own `views.py`:

```
from external_app.views import upload_view

@login_required
def custom_upload_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     # Do something before
     ...
     return upload_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

You just need to make sure you have your own URL pattern pointing to your custom view in your url config before the external apps urls

Comment: can I add them into any existing view ? or should I create new app for this purpose ?